# Android: Changing background selector resource on view does not update

Tags: android

The problem seems like a simple one and I dug around in the Android source but the cause of the issue is not apparent.

Effectively, this is what I am doing

```
if(condition) {
    view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selector1);
}else {
    view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selector2);
}
```

The view is not in a list but it is reused. If I make this change during a click event and I have `enterFadeDuration` and `exitFadeDuration` defined in my selector resource, then the appropriate drawable is rendered (I am assuming the animation forces a redraw). However, if I make this change while the view is hidden and then set visiblity to visible, the updated selector is not drawn. Subsequently, if I press on the view, the selector is then rendered correctly.

My guess is that an Android optimization is preventing the background resource from being updated. I have tried the obvious options such as `invalidate()` and `requestLayout()` after setting the new background selector. Is there another way I can force the view to update with the new background selector?

Note: Only tested on KitKat (4.4.4)

Comment: put some code not just the if-else statement..

Comment: I will have to contrive an example to show this problem using a minimum amount of code. Waiting to see if anyone had any similar experiences and perhaps could provide a low hanging fruit solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Rod_Algonquin pointed out, I should have shown more code. While I was creating a sample project to reproduce this issue, I found the problem. I will describe my solution below for reference.

I temporarily disable the view that has the selector updated. When I enable the view, it seems the selector is looking for a `state_enabled="true"` item. Without this, no selector is applied. I had hoped/expected that the default selector item would be picked up but with the addition of the `state_enabled` selector item entry, the view updates as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You might not be changing the background through UI thread. Try this:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (condition) {
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selector1);
        } else {
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selector2);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I verified that the code was being executed on UI thread. I even tried using this approach but unfortunately, the problem did not resolve.